# Mongoose Automatically Decreases Field with Type of Number

Tags: javascript, database, mongoose, automation, backend

i have used mongoose for my project currently, and this is my Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const classSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  consultant: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Consultant',
    required: true,
  },
  faculty: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Faculty',
    required: true,
  },
  startYear: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  currentSchoolYear: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  currentSemester: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  classname: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  classSize: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  warnedLength: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
});

const Class = mongoose.model('Class', classSchema);

module.exports = Class;
```

as you can see, i have 2 properties are `classSize` and `warnedLength` are Number. Now i want to make a function that when i onClick a button from the client, the value of `classSize` and `warnedLength` will automatically decrease by 1. is there anyway to do that, thank you so much for help me out, it means a lot to me, have a good day

Comment: You can use `$inc: {classSize: -1, warnedLength: -1}`

Comment: thank you so much, it works, in case you are vietnamese: "Em cảm ơn anh rất nhiều, em đã thử và nó đã chạy thành công"